# How to define path to import python library

Tags: python, linux, macos, import, xgboost

I have a MacBook Pro and successfully installed `xgboost` on it. If I start a Python shell in `~/xgboost/python-package` I can easily import `xgboost` by running the command:

```
import xgboost
```

But if I go to some other folder, start the python shell and run the above command I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named xgboost
```

I am guessing this is related to `$PATH`. How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the directory in the pythonpath so python knows where to look at:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/your/path/to/your/module
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it the same if I add the above to `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: Yes this should do as well. I do not remember if it is in .bash_profile or .bashrc though. Maybe you can try both. Then do not forget to take the changes into account using `source .bash_profile` (or `source .bashrc` )